# Android:hex code to binary and then binary to base64 string

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to convert a hex code which I receive

```
 20 12 B3

 5C A9
 
 6D 11
```

I am storing the hexvalues in a val as below.

```
      val hexValues = "6B38208A4D0D6D11756F9B21B3395BD4FE427BEE76FE4760B09FCC5E2D76CC"
```

I am trying to check if the above is hexcode or not then converting to binary.

But the code I have written  always returns false saying the above is not hexcode.

STEP1:

```
              private fun isHexDec(cadena: String): Boolean {

              if (cadena.isEmpty() ||cadena[0] != '-' &&. 
             (cadena[0].digitToIntOrNull(16) ?: -1) == -1
                  ) return false
                if (cadena.length == 1 && cadena[0] == '-') return false
              for (i in 1 until cadena.length) if 
(cadena[i].digitToIntOrNull(16) ?: -1 
    == -1) return false
    return true
      }
```

and also tried this function to detect

```
    private fun isHexadecimal(s: String): Boolean {
    return s.chars().allMatch { c: Int -> 
   "0123456789ABCDEFabcdef".indexOf(c.toChar()) >= 0 }
      }
```

both the above functions returns **false**

STEP2:the below code will return binary from hexcode.

```
    private fun hexToBin(s: String?): String? {
    return BigInteger(s, 16).toString(2)
     }
```

After this I have to convert the binary data to base64 string

Any help would be highly appreciated
Thanks

Comment: Please put the hex values in a String variable at the start of your code. After that show how you call isDecHex() with that string. Also show how you call other functions with it.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.I am getting the hex values in a json response so I am taking them and storing in val like this  val hexvalues =
                                        valParams.getNullableString("hexval") as String

Comment: passing the hexvalues to the functions I have written but no luck

Comment: We are not interested where you get them from. Well not at the moment. You should show exactly what you have in String `hexvalues`. So you could start your post with something like `String hexvalues = "20 12 B3...."`. Now please do. Post reproducable code. If we wanted to test your code we need such a prefabricated string. You have to deliver it.

Comment: Thanks a lot @blackapps .after a codecleanup its working now.I have updated my question as its incomplete.Thanks again for the suggestion.

Comment: If it is working now then what is the question?